# ignore ( or do not print ) find warning bash

Tags: bash

I wrote a bash script that search text file in the current directory and all subdirectories.

When I pass  `~/file.txt` as argument the command

```
$(find . -name "$i")
```

it prints to the terminal the warning:

> find: warning: ‘-name’ matches against basenames only, but the given pattern contains a directory separator (‘/’), thus the expression will evaluate to false all the time.  Did you mean ‘-wholename’?

Is there an option to ignore that command and not print it?

Comment: Why do you want to suppress the warning? It comes from `find` (not from `bash`), and it's trying to tell you that your command probably doesn't do what you expect. If you really want to suppress it, you can add `2>/dev/null` to redirect stderr to the null device, but I'd rather fix the problem: either don't pass a path or use `-wholename` (or `-path`). See [`man find`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)

Comment: my task is to search a text file from an argument i get, in the currect directory or all sub-directories . it all work well until i get this as argument:   ~/test.txt 
it print the error while it actually do find the file

Comment: @ndgqdhwk : The warning basically says in nice words: "Your find expression is nonsense, but if you want to shoot yourself in the foot, go ahead!". I now wonder why you want to suppress this helpful message....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hacky approach could be like this: `find . -name "$i" 2> /dev/null` as `find` command prints warnings and errors to `stderr`.

Be aware of this warning may tell you about misusing the `find` util.

Comment: i don't understand, that does other error, should i write:

insubdir="$(find . -name <...> 2> /dev/null "$i")"   ?

that is the command i write inside loop

Comment: You may `insubdir="$(find . -name "$i" 2> /dev/null)"`